# How can I solve this without using the L'Hôpital's Rule?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $$\large\lim_{x\to -\frac{3}{2}}  \frac{2x^2+5x+3}{|2x+3|}$$

How can I compute this without using L'Hôpital's Rule?

Comment: factorize the quadratic

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule is unsuitable here anyway.

Comment: (also, in general L'Hospital is a pretty big hammer, and very often is overkill... it shouldn't be the first impulse to use it, at least in my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

$$2x^2+5x+3=(2x+3)(x+1)$$

Now for real $y,\; |y|=\begin{cases} y &\mbox{if } y\ge0 \\ -y & \mbox{if } y<0\end{cases}$

Observe that the left & the right limits are different, hence the limit does not exist

Comment: Pointless. Let the questioner have a go.

Comment: @Paul, Not sure if I've understood your point?

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\large\lim_{x\to -\frac{3}{2}^+}  \frac{2x^2+5x+3}{|2x+3|}=\large\lim_{x\to -\frac{3}{2}^+}  \frac{2x^2+5x+3}{2x+3}=\large\lim_{x\to -\frac{3}{2}^+}  x+1=-\frac12.$$

and $$\large\lim_{x\to -\frac{3}{2}^-}  \frac{2x^2+5x+3}{|2x+3|}=\large\lim_{x\to -\frac{3}{2}^-} - \frac{2x^2+5x+3}{2x+3}=\large\lim_{x\to -\frac{3}{2}^-} -( x+1)=\frac12.$$

We can conclude this limit doesn't exist!